# Date difference function in snowflake is giving one more count for same query in DB2

Tags: java, sql, db2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are migrating from DB2 to Snowflake. For the same query in DB2 and snowflake the datediff() of snowflake is giving count more then one for some of the values not for all campared to Days() of DB2.Most of values are matching. I am generating query dynamically in java and sending it snowflake to execute.

Db2 Query:

```
Select 
'1' as fromPattern, Cast(p1.patternnumber as varchar(20)) as fromCode,
'2' as toPattern, Cast(p2.patternnumber as varchar(20)) as toCode,
Cast(Cast(count(*) as Integer) as varchar(20)) as num,
Cast(Cast(avg(Days(p2.datepointer) - Days(p1.stopdate)) as Integer) as varchar(20)) as avgGap 
from TenMillion_20220731.NS8661_562_20231109_104300_097 p1 
join TenMillion_20220731.NS8661_564_20231109_104338_543 p2 on p1.personid=p2.personid 
group by p1.patternnumber, p2.patternnumber 
order by fromPattern, toPattern, fromCode, toCode
```

Snowflake Query:

```
Select 
'1' as fromPattern, Cast(p1.patternnumber as varchar(20)) as fromCode,
'2' as toPattern, Cast(p2.patternnumber as varchar(20)) as toCode,
Cast(Cast(count(*) as Integer) as varchar(20)) as num,
Cast(Cast(avg(datediff(day,p1.stopdate,p2.datepointer)) as Integer) as varchar(20)) as avgGap 
from TenMillion_20220731.NS10386_147_20231108_235900_717 p1 
join TenMillion_20220731.NS10386_149_20231108_235900_717 p2 on p1.personid=p2.personid 
group by p1.patternnumber, p2.patternnumber 
order by fromPattern, toPattern, fromCode, toCode
```

Db2 Output:
[image]

SnowFlake Output:
[image]

AVGGAP column for DB2 is date difference column which has values 619 and 340 in DB2 but in snowflake is 620 and 341 respectively. Other values are matching except two.

Can anyone please help me to understand why same function is giving same as well as different values. Its vary important to understand this issue because its data mismatch in our application which needs to clarify to vendor. Please help.

Thanks,
Prabhash Mishra

Comment: are you certain that the datepointer and stopdate contain just the dates and no time parts?

Comment: No there is no time part in db.

Comment: It is only 29 entries, select individual values (aggregation) for that subset, and see which is different (if any). Is there a difference between how the cast function is implemented between DB2 and SF?

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?  What are the actual dates involved when there's a difference?